# ABC conjecture and Fermat's last theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, abc-conjecture

I have frequently read and heard that given the ABC-conjecture a number of important unsolved problems of number theory can be solved (with relatively simple proofs). Among them, the celebrated Fermat's Last theorem is frequently mentioned.

So, my question is: Given that the $ABC$ conjecture is valid, can we prove that it implies Fermat's Last theorem ?

**P.S.:** I can understand that ABC conjecture "easily" implies the *asymptotic FLT*  (stating that: "the equ-ation $x^n+y^n=z^n$ can have solutions in positive integers only for $n< n_0$, where $n_0$ is some finite number"). This is outlined in Lang's Algebra (p.196, 1994 edition), see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209470/asymptotic-flt-impliesflt-using-abc-conjecture) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130980/effect-of-abc-conjecture-on-fermats-last-theorem).

Comment: No.  The largeness of exponents in the asymptotic version depends crucially on what constant emerges (for a given specific epsilon) in an ABC proof.  In particular, if ABC were to be proved with ineffective constants then the "largeness" would be totally mysterious, and Vesselin Dimitrov's "effective" version of Mochizuki's result (*assuming* the latter as a black box!) gives horrifically gigantic constants (massive exponentials, etc.).  For this and other reasons, the proof of FLT via modularity methods seems likely to remain the only way to prove FLT and to understand why it is true.

Comment: No, abc implies at most finitely many counterexamples to FLT, but it allows counterexamples.

Comment: Actually, it isn't _that_ inconceivable that ABC implies FLT, even though not in the obvious way - we might e.g. be able to prove that if there is a solution with exponent $n$, then there is a solution with an exponent $m>n$, in which case we would get a contradiction with ABC. I am not claiming I know how to prove FLT from ABC this way, just sharing a thought.

Comment: @ nfdc23: thank you for the account and thanks for mentioning Vesselin Dimitrov's "effective" version of Mochizuki's result. It is an interesting paper. It can be found at http://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03572. Hope there are more to follow.

Comment: @Wojowu: thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Here's one way to think about it. $ABC$ easily implies that if $n$ is sufficiently large, then the equation $X^n+Y^n=94151567435Z^n$ has no solutions in non-zero integers. But it could not imply that there are no  solutions for all $n$, since in fact $(2,3,1)$ is a solution for $n=23$. So $ABC$ will, as others have said, rule out all sufficiently large $n$ (even for more general equations such as $aX^n+bY^n=cZ^n$), but then one will need some method of dealing with the remaining values of $n$.

Comment: Subsumed by http://mathoverflow.net/q/130980/41291 (imo)

Comment: If this conjecture https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303141/is-the-conjecture-ab-c-following-correct is true, then Fermat's Last theorem, Beal conjecture, Fermat-Catalan conjecture are special case

Answer (score 8):

No, abc doesn't imply FLT.

For all exponents $n > 3$, abc implies at most finitely many counterexamples to FLT, but it allows counterexamples to FLT.

For exponent $n=3$ it allows infinitely many counterexamples
and the Fermat-like equation $x^3+y^3=a z^3$ has infinitely many
coprime solutions for some $a$ via the group law on the elliptic curve.

Basically finite number of abc triples of arbitrary quality don't contradict
abc, while a single counterexample contradicts FLT.

Also, there is generalization of abc over number fields, widely believed to be true.

Over number fields FLT fails, e.g. $1^n+1^n=(\sqrt[n]{2})^n$.